# VS 2017 15.7.3 Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I thought this was solved last year with 15.3...
Trying to build a CORE 2.0 project, using both VS 2017 15.6.5, and VS 2017 15.7.3, I get the dreaded Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web not found error message.

I've tried various suggestions from SO:

- Edited the csproj file to  from
  Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.
- Made sure C:\Program Files\dotnet came first in the path variable.
- Checked on Global.json but found it didn't exist and that this is
  expected.
- Several other suggestions from around the Google-verse.

Interestingly dotnet build works just fine. So, I think it has to be a configuration error of some sort, somewhere.

Environment: 
VS 2017 15.7.3
dotnet 2.1.200-preview-007517 (also erred with 2.1.104 and 2.1.4)
CORE 2.0 AspnetCore Web Application -- MVC

Any suggestions appreciated.

Randy

Comment: `Help | Send Feedback` please. The preview build has many bugs (I reported one and they did not fix yet).

Comment: Did you manage to find out the cause? I'm having the same issue with VS 15.5.6